# TargetInvocationException by calling Invoke

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Why I'm getting *TargetInvocationException?*

```
class Master : IMaster {}
class MobileMenu : MyUserControl {
    public MobileMenu(IMaster _master) {}
}
static class Program {
  public static Master ContainerPage;
  static void Main() {
    ContainerPage = new Master();
    Type t = typeof(MobileMenu);
    ConstructorInfo constructor = t.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IMaster) });
    MyUserControl uc = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { ContainerPage }) as MyUserControl;
    ContainerPage.LoadPage(uc);
  }
}
```

At Invoke I get the mentioned exception which want to meaning that constructor can not be found. As you can see MobileMenu has the prior ctor.

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: That's quite normal.  The standard mistake is forgetting to look at the InnerException for the reason the invoked code failed.  Best way to debug is with Debug > Exceptions > Thrown checkbox.

Comment: Why not use `Activator.CreateInstance` instead? It can take a list of objects, which it matches to the constructor parameter types. Will make your code simpler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: InnerException is NullReferenceException... I don't understand why. _ContainerPage_ (which is static in this class), _t_ and _constructor_ all have values.

Comment: .net 3.5 Compact Framework doesn't support Activator.CreateInstance with two parameters, it has only one parameter: the type to instantiate.

Comment: @Franziee Perhaps the cast with `as` fails?

Comment: without casting (in immediate window) I get the exception as well